# regexp to match sequence if not starting and ending with a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

When it comes to regexps, I'm not very good at finding one that works and suits my needs.I need to match a word say foo if it is not included between a character say [ and another character say ]

```
 "[foo] foo" // I need to replace foo with bar
 // expected result : "[foo] bar" but not "[bar] bar"
```

I know how to match it if it is not *followed* by ]

```
 "foo] foo".replace(/foo(!?\])/g,"bar")
```

And I also know how to match it if it is not *preceded* by [

```
 " [foo foo".replace(/(\[)?foo/g,function(_0,_1) {
      return _1:_0?"bar"
 })
```

But I don't know how to put them together.Thank you!

Comment: Try with `/(^|[^\[])foo/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a negative lookahead you can use this regex:

```
var repl = str.replace(/\bfoo\b(?![^\]\[]*\])/g, 'bar');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r92RFL/1)

`(?![^\]\[]*\])` is a negative lookahead assertion. This asserts failure when it finds a `]` without matching `[` or `]` on the way, thus not matching `foo` inside `[...]`.

`\b` is used for word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this to match a word between [ and ]

```
"[foo] foo".match(/\[.*?\]/g)
```

Comment: I was looking for a regex to match foo if *not* between [ and ]

Answer (score 0):

You need the following regex:

```
(?<!\[)foo(?!])
```

it has negative lookbehind for `[` and negative lookahead for `]`.

Comment: I was for a solution in js since I added the javascript tag.Js does not support negative look behind.